# itext PdfACopy loses OutputIntent

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfa, color-profile

I want to concatenate PDF/A 1b files.

I'm using itext's `PdfACopy.getImportedPage` and there's no error. Itext's conformance checks are fine.

I get a PDF/A 1b file that seems alright.

When I check my PDF/A conformance using [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/pdfavalidation.html) I get a lot of errors :

> ```
> 2.4.3 : Invalid Color space, DestOutputProfile is missing
> 2.4.3 : Invalid Color space, The operator "g" can't be used without Color Profile
> 2.4.3 : Invalid Color space, The operator "f" can't be used without Color Profile
> 2.4.1 : Invalid Color space, The operator "rg" can't be used with CMYK Profile
> 2.4.3 : Invalid Color space, DestOutputProfile is missing
> ```

NB : all input PDF are valid PDF/A 1b

Here's the sample code I used to get the PDF/A that doesn't conform to PDF/A 1b

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfACopy copy = new PdfACopy(document, new FileOutputStream(outFile), pdfAConformanceLevel);

document.open();

PdfReader reader;
int n;
for (int i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++)
{
  reader = new PdfReader(args[i]);
  n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
  for (int page = 0; page < n;)
  {
    copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
  }

}

copy.createXmpMetadata();

document.close();
```

So I got mad and decided to sort it out.

Using this example [dump ICC profile from PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740175/how-do-i-dump-embedded-icc-profile-information-in-pdf-command-line-or-gui-tool) I can see that indeed no ICC profiles were included in my generated PDF/A.

After looking at this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bLFO4ZV0i4), I finally used the code in `PdfWriter.setOutputIntents(final PdfReader reader, final boolean checkExistence)` to get the output intents in the input PDF/A and put it back into the output PDF/A.

And it works...

I first created a public method

```
public static void copyOutputIntents(PdfReader reader, PdfACopy copy) throws IOException {


    PdfDictionary catalog = reader.getCatalog();

    PdfArray outs = catalog.getAsArray(PdfName.OUTPUTINTENTS);
    if (outs == null)
    {
        Logger.err("Reggie Watts gonna get you !!!");
    }
    else
    {
        if (outs.isEmpty())
        {
            Logger.err("Reggie Watts gonna get you !!!");
        }
        PdfDictionary out = outs.getAsDict(0);

        PRStream stream = (PRStream) PdfReader.getPdfObject(out.get(PdfName.DESTOUTPUTPROFILE));
        byte destProfile[] = null;
        if (stream != null)
        {
            destProfile = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
        }
        copy.setOutputIntents(getNameString(out, PdfName.OUTPUTCONDITIONIDENTIFIER), getNameString(out, PdfName.OUTPUTCONDITION), getNameString(out, PdfName.REGISTRYNAME), getNameString(out, PdfName.INFO), destProfile);

    }
}
```

had also to add `getNameString` method that I simply bulk copied.

So now my code now produces valid PDF/A :

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfACopy copy = new PdfACopy(document, new FileOutputStream(outFile), pdfAConformanceLevel);

document.open();

PdfReader reader;
int n;
for (int i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++)
{
  reader = new PdfReader(args[i]);
  n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
  for (int page = 0; page < n;)
  {
    copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
  }
  // get last PDF's intent and put it into the output one
  Stamper.copyOutputIntents(reader, copy);
}

copy.createXmpMetadata();

document.close();
```

Shouldn't `PdfACopy.addPage` keep the output intent of the added page or handle it in any way ?

I can't see the point in having a high level class that cannot produce valid PDF/A file.

Am I missing something ? Have I gone crazy ?

Sorry for the long post.

Comment: The output intents are set at the document level, not at the page level. See for instance [PdfA1A](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/pdfa/PdfA1A): `writer.setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);` With `PdfACopy`, you create a new `writer` (`PdfACopy` extends `PdfWriter`). You need to add these intents in your code, because `PdfACopy` can't decide which to use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and great job. As the javadoc description of PdfACopy is `"Extension of PdfCopy that will attempt to keep a file in conformance with the PDF/A standard."` , I thought it would get the necessary objects from the copied page but you're right, I have to work at document level like for  the XMP metadata.